# Flatten array in PHP by calculating the average number for the same keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in PHP that shows an average number per month. Now this array can contain multiple entries for the same month. If that is the case, the numbers have to be summed up and divided by the count of entries per month:

E.g. May = (3.15 + 2.29 + 2.36) / 3 = 2.6

Input:

```
$result = [
    0 => ['April' => 4.36],
    1 => ['May' => 3.15],
    2 => ['May' => 2.29],
    3 => ['May' => 2.36]
];
```

Output:

```
$result = [
    [0] => ['April' => 4.36],
    [1] => ['May' => 2.60]
];
```

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: just have a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43964532/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here In the first loop we are iterating over input array to gather values according to `month`, and in second loop we are using `array_walk` to loop-over the array to find average. using function `array_sum` and `count`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794746)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$Array = [
    0 => ['April' => 4.36],
    1 => ['May' => 3.15],
    2 => ['May' => 2.29],
    3 => ['May' => 2.36]
];
$result=array();
//Gathering values according to months.
foreach ($Array as $value)
{
    $result[key($value)][]=$value[key($value)];//using key function to get the first key of array
}
//using array_sum for finding sum of array.
array_walk($result,function($value,$key) use (&$newResult){
   $newResult[] = array($key =>array_sum($value)/count($value));
});
print_r($newResult);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to make a small edit due to the fact that i do have multiple arrays. Do you think your function works with this as well? Cheers

Comment: @doonot Yaah sure, It will work fine, if you have a big array in the same format

Comment: @doonot i didn't understand. For what, i have to update?

Comment: The input array changed, please check the question above.

Comment: @doonot I did that you can check now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144174/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-doonot).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-dimensional arrays.

Multi-dimensional arrays are arrays in arrays, how many ever times you wish.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

So, relating to you code, let's say November has these numbers: 
4,3,2 and 1.

You would do this:

```
$result = array(
 "November" => array(4,3,2,1)
)
```

Then you would find the length of the array, access the multi-dimensional objects by doing this:

```
$result["November"][0]
```

(This will output 4)

Then write a foreach script to determine the average. I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 0):

try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/794739)**

```
$array = [];
foreach($result as $v)
{
  $array[key($v)][] = current($v);
}
$result = array_map(function($v){return array_sum($v)/count($v);}, $array);
```